# type in Scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, types, enumeration

From the [enumeration Scala document](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration), I have this example.

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    type WeekDay = Value
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

However It seems like that it works fine without `type WeekDay = Value`. 
What's it for? When can we skip this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
type WeekDay = Value
```

It's just a type alias, you don't need it but it can be useful, consider this:

```
object SomeObject {
  import WeekDay._

  val someDay: WeekDay = Fri
}
```

Once you imported the object you can declare variables of type `WeekDay`, if instead you don't have a type alias your variables will be defined so:

```
object SomeObject {
  val someDay: WeekDay.Value = WeekDay.Mon
}
```

It simply allows some brevity when dealing with the enumeration values.